# How to for loop a multiparty file upload?

Tags: node.js, azure, http-post, azure-blob-storage, multipart

I am building a website for a customer and they need to upload **multiple files** (this is important) to an Azure Blob Storage container. I currently use this code:

```
app.post("/upload", function (req, res) {
     var blobService = azure.createBlobService("mainwebsite", "XXX");
     var form        = new multiparty.Form();
     form.on("part", function(part) {
        if(part.filename) {
            var size = part.byteCount - part.byteOffset;
            var name = part.filename;
            blobService.createBlockBlobFromStream("images", name, part, size, function(error) {
                res.send({ success: "Your file(s) have been uploaded successfully."});
            });
        } else {
            return;
        }
    });
    form.parse(req);
});
```

I need to change this code so that it enumerates over all the files passed into the POST request. Could someone please shed some light on this for me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage function [createWriteStreamToBlockBlob()](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/master/lib/services/blob/blobservice.js#L2961) which will return a `writeStream` then `pipe` the parts into the `writeStream`, here is the code snippet:

```
router.get('/multipart', function (req, res){
    res.send(
        '<form action="/test/multipart" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">' +
        '<input type="file" name="upload[]" multip le="multiple"><br>' +
        '<input type="file" name="upload[]" multiple="multiple"><br>' +
        '<input type="submit" value="Upload">' +
        '</form>'
    )
})
router.post('/multipart', function (req, res) {
    var form = new multiparty.Form({});
    var files = [];
    var finished = [];
    form.on("part", function (part) {
        if (part.filename) {
            var size = part.byteCount - part.byteOffset;
            var name = part.filename;
            var out = blobsrv.createWriteStreamToBlockBlob("images", name);
            out.on("finish", function () {
                console.log("finish upload file: " + name);
                finished.push(name);
                if (finished.length == files.length) {
                    res.send(JSON.stringify(finished))
                }
            })
            part.on('end', function () {
                console.log('part end')
                files.push(name);
            })
            part.pipe(out)
        } else {
            return;
        }
    });

    form.parse(req);
})
```

Comment: I get a "Request Aborted" error when I run that. Here is the stack trace: https://gist.github.com/nhubbard/edc581e7afb51397997c

Comment: What the sizes of your upload files? Here is a similar issue with your maybe you can refer to https://github.com/andrewrk/node-multiparty/issues/118. And if it is convenient of you, could you please provide your code snippet which will raise the issue for us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Never mind, I had a very obscure syntax error. Happens to the best of us. :-) Your answer has been marked as correct.